# H61M-P23 B3 With I5 2500k - Is the multiplier locked?

Tags: motherboard, overclocking

I have seen a couple posts in some random places that say you cannot use an unlocked processor (K) with the 'H61M-P23 B3' motherboard. Can anyone verify this with a reference or explain their certainty? The posts in question all seem to state that a P67 board is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, if you [take this](http://www.pugetsystems.com/blog/2011/06/09/h67-p67-and-z68-which-one-is-right-for-you/) article about different chipsets as an example (one of the first results google showed).

about the H67:

> The downside is the H67 supports only very limited overclocking [...]

and about the P67:

> It [P67] also is capable of being overclocked, and that combination of features have made it popular for gamers and other demanding users.

The [board](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/H61M-P23--B3-.html) from your question only uses the H61 chipset, but regarding your question the answer is the same.